# Cannot get log4net to work for database

Tags: log4net

I cannot get log4net to work, and having installed Glimpse for log4net, I notice the log4net tab is greyed out, so I guess I have not installed it properly, not sure where though.

In my assemblyInfo.cs I have:

```cs
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

It may not be necessary, but in Global.asax.cs I have:

```cs
var logConfigFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/log4net.config");
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo(logConfigFilePath));
```

In my log4net.config I have:

```xml
?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

    <system.web>
            <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
    </configSections>
    <log4net>
        <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
            <bufferSize value="100" />
            <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, 
     System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            <connectionString value="data source=SQL_Mulalley;initial catalog=LogFiles;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=***;Password=****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
            <commandText value="INSERT INTO SCD4_Log4Net ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
            <parameter>
                <parameterName value="@log_date" />
                <dbType value="DateTime" />
                <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <parameterName value="@thread" />
                <dbType value="String" />
                <size value="255" />
                <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                    <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
                </layout>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <parameterName value="@log_level" />
                <dbType value="String" />
                <size value="50" />
                <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                    <conversionPattern value="%level" />
                </layout>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <parameterName value="@logger" />
                <dbType value="String" />
                <size value="255" />
                <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                    <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
                </layout>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <parameterName value="@message" />
                <dbType value="String" />
                <size value="4000" />
                <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                    <conversionPattern value="%message" />
                </layout>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <parameterName value="@exception" />
                <dbType value="String" />
                <size value="2000" />
                <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
            </parameter>
        </appender>
        <root>
            <level value="FATAL"/>
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
        </root>
    </log4net>
</configuration>
```

I obtain the logger here:

```cs
private static readonly log4net.ILog log =
            log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

And I call the log in my code as follows:

```cs
log.Info(string.Format("User {0} logged in.", model.UserName));
```

Nothing appears in my database where I have created the standard Log4Net table.
So what am I missing?

Comment: Your `Log4NetLogger` class is completely useless and loses class information.  Use log4net directly.

Comment: I replaced it with         private static readonly log4net.ILog log = 
            log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType); but still does not work.

Comment: I edited the question and removed the class that is not needed.

Comment: did you get finally a solution to problem?

Comment: No, I must be missing something simple but I cant see what it is.

Answer (score 0):

You did declare the appender but `log4net` is not actually using it.

As per your config file you're telling `log4net` to use an appender named `RollingFileAppender` (that is, additionally, not defined).

Change this:

```xml
<appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
```

To:

```xml
<appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender"/>
```

Finally pay attention to this section:

```xml
    <root>
        <level value="FATAL"/>
```

As per the line above, your (default) appender is not going to transmit any log unless you do the logs with `Fatal` level:

```cs
 log.Fatal(string.Format("User {0} logged in.", model.UserName));
```

Or change the default log-level to debug:

```xml
    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be the buffer size is 100 and hence you haven't hit the buffer limit to allow log4net to write to Db. Change it to one for testing

```
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
        <bufferSize value="100" />
```

You can also see if the Adoappender is throwing any error by switching on Internal.Debug=true

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

I usually get issue with the SQL not being correct or the connection string is not correct.